# Fitting 4-moment distribution with mixture gaussian

Tags: r, distributions, optimization, mixture-distribution

I know that Mclust does the fit on its own but I am trying to implement an optimization with the aim to generate a mixture of 2 gaussians with the combine moments as closed as possible to the moment of my returns' distribution.

The objective is to

`Min Abs((Mean Ret - MeanFit)/Mean Fit) + Abs((Std Ret -Stdev Fit)/Stdev) + Abs((Sk Ret-Sk fit)/Sk Fit) + Abs((Kurt Ret- Kurt Fit))`

Taking into account that I fix the weight between the two gaussians at (0.2;0.8) I implement the below code in R:

```
distance <-function(parameter,x) { 
 u=mean(x) 
 s=sd(x) 
 sk=skewness(x) 
 kurt=kurtosis(x) 
 d1=dnorm(x,parameter[1],parameter[2]) 
 d2=dnorm(x,parameter[3],parameter[4]) 
 dfit=0.2d1+0.8d2 
 ufit=mean(dfit) 
 sdfit=sd(dfit) 
 skfit=skewness(fit) 
 kurtfit=kurtosis(fit) 


 abs((u-ufit)/ufit)+abs(s-sdfit)/sdfit)+abs((sk-skfit)/skfit)+abs((kurt-kurtfit)/kurtfit)) 
} 
Parameter<-c(0,0.01,0,0.01)  # starting point of the optimization 
opp<-optim(parameter,distance,x=conv)
```

1. could anybody tell me whether it is the right approach ?
2. should I add some constraint like 
   `ufit=0.2*mean(d1)+0.8*mean(d2)...`

thank you very much in advance for your time and help.

Sam

Comment: I am concerned about your objective function.  It will be unstable when exploring values where 'Mean Fit' and 'Sk Fit' are near zero, even if these are close to (or at) the optimum.  One wonders about the point of optimizing the sum of relative errors, too.  After all, the uncertainties in the moments get larger as the order goes up: the mean return is a *far* better estimate of the true mean than the kurtosis of the returns is an estimate of the true kurtosis. A natural objective would be something like the sum of the squared differences of the $1/k$ powers of the sizes of the $k$th moments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I have used the moment method and I think I am on the right track.
Best Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 5):

I am not exactly sure what your code is trying to do, but it seems like you should be using $rnorm()$ (with a large $n$) instead of $dnorm()$, since the functions $mean()$, $var()$, etc. are designed to be used on samples, not densities.

In any case, using the method-of-moments is easy to do algebraically.

Let's say your sample is $X=[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$.  Your sample moments are:

$$m_1(X) = (1/n) \sum_{i} x_i$$
$$m_2(X) = (1/n) \sum_{i} x_i^2$$
$$m_3(X) = (1/n) \sum_{i} x_i^3$$
$$m_4(X) = (1/n) \sum_{i} x_i^4$$

The moments of $Z \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ are:

$$m_1(Z) = \mu$$
$$m_2(Z) = \mu^2 + \sigma^2$$
$$m_3(Z) = \mu^3 + 3\mu\sigma^2$$
$$m_4(Z) = \mu^3 + 6\mu^2\sigma^2 + 3(\sigma^2)^2$$

Furthermore, if your random variable $Y$ is a mixture of $Z_1, Z_2, \cdots, Z_m$, with $P[X=Z_i]=p_i$, then

$$m_1(Y) = p_1 m_1(Z_1) + p_2 m_1 (Z_2) + \cdots + p_m m_1 (Z_m)$$
$$m_2(Y) = p_1 m_2(Z_1) + p_2 m_2 (Z_2) + \cdots + p_m m_1 (Z_m)$$
$$\cdots$$

If you use enough gaussians you should be able to match a finite number of moments exactly.  Under constraint you may need to define a distance metric on your moments vector $(m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4)$.  The euclidean distance should work fine but you will want to differentially weight the moments, since the higher-order moments could be very large or very small depending on what distribution you are working with.  Also, the first and second moments are generally more important.